# How to make the script stop at specified time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sikuli

I have 100 list of software.
I have this code:

```
doubleClick("1380765362298.png")
wait(0.01)
#mouseDown(Button.LEFT)
#mouseUp(Button.LEFT)
while exists("1380774111845.png",10):
    click("1380774111845.png")
    wait(0.01)
    mouseDown(Button.LEFT)
    mouseUp(Button.LEFT)
    wait(2)
#except:
    #pass
    try:
        click("1380765740907.png")
        wait(3)
        waitVanish("1380772439126.png",FOREVER)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        click("1380769537610.png")
        wait(4)

    except:
        pass
    try:
        click("1380772563891.png")
        wait(2)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        type(Key.DELETE)
        wait(2)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        click("1380774317204.png")
        wait(1)
    except:
        pass
else:
    pass
```

In this code, I tried to make it loop until 10 but it wont work.
It will keep looping until all software have been run.
So how can I make it loop until 10 only?

Comment: Which thing do you want to do 10 times?

Comment: Run the 1380774111845.png for 10 times only

Comment: You want this to end after 10 seconds?

Comment: @theBigChalk its not 10 seconds. I mean 10 times loop.

Comment: I`ve never used sikuli, but docs says   :
exists(PS[, seconds])
    Check whether the give pattern is visible on the screen.
    Parameters: 
        PS – a Pattern object or a string (path to an image file or just plain text)
        seconds – a number, which can have a fraction, as maximum waiting time in seconds. The internal granularity is milliseconds. If not specified, the auto wait timeout value set by Region.setAutoWaitTimeout() is used. Use the constant FOREVER to wait for an infinite time.

So we are talking about seconds in while loop, not times.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop will execute as long as 1380774111845.png is on screen. If you only want it to execute 10 times, replace the while with a for loop:

```
for x in range(10):
   if not exists("1380774111845.png",10):
       break
```

Also, remove the final else/pass as it's unnecessary.